# passing a series of values (one dimensional array or a vector) from rstudio to Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, rstudio, fortran77

I am trying to pass a series of numbers from rstudio to a fortran77 subroutine and receive back in rstudio a series of numbers from the result of the F77 subroutine.

My R code is:

```
n <- 10
rtairsent <- c(rep(3, n))
rtairback <- c(rep(1, n))

mySENSRange <- function(irtairsent, rtairback) {
  if (!is.loaded('rwrapper')) {
    dyn.load("rwrapper.so")
  }
  retvals <- .Fortran("RSTACKSEN",rtairsent = as.array(rtairsent[1:10]),
                      rtairback = as.array(rtairback[1:10]))
  return(retvals$rtairback)
}
mySENSRange(rtairsent, rtairback)
```

And my Fortran77 subroutine is:

```
     SUBROUTINE RSTACKSEN(RTAIRIN,RTAIROUT)

     dimension rtairin(10),rtairout(10)
     real rtairin,rtairout

     do 18 i=1,10
       rtairout(i)=rtairin(i)+1.
       write(6,*) rtairout(i),rtairin(i),'inside'
18   continue          
     RETURN
     END
```

When I run this from Rstudio I get the write(6,*) and the retvals output as (this is tab delimited and a separate line after the word "inside" but I can not format it here):

```
   1.00000000       0.00000000     inside
   3.12500000       2.12500000     inside
   1.00000000       0.00000000     inside
   3.12500000       2.12500000     inside
   1.00000000       0.00000000     inside
   3.12500000       2.12500000     inside
   1.00000000       0.00000000     inside
   3.12500000       2.12500000     inside
   1.00000000       0.00000000     inside
   3.12500000       2.12500000     inside
```

`[1] 48.00001 48.00001 48.00001 48.00001 48.00001  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000`

BUT what I would actually like to get is (I don't mind if the real number is not exactly equal to the integer):

```
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
   4.00000000       3.00000000     inside
```

`[1] 4.00000 4.00000 4.00000 4.00000 4.00000  4.00000  4.00000  4.00000  4.00000  4.00000`

I can't explain the numbers that I am getting so I would appreciate your help. Obviously I am a beginner with R and I am not an advanced user of Fortran either.

Thank you so much. Happy to provide more explanation about the code if required.

Comment: Wild guess, does R work with double precision arrays (8byte) or real (4 byte arrays)? Print also the input in R.

Comment: You are great guys, thanks. The definition of the variables as real in the fortran code was the issue of the problem. Changing to double precision works well!